# Can we change app icon dynamically without requiring store update?

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, themes

How do companies change their app icon in holiday seasons? Is that possible to achieve without store update?

And what list of changes that can be done to change app style dynamically to support marketing campaigns like having special app appearance in holiday seasons?

What I can understand is having server-side style definition and fetching it on app launch to customize the:
1- splash screen
2- app colors
3- fonts

Is there any other recommendations? what are the technical limitations?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-change-your-app-icon-dynamically-with-setalternateiconname

Comment: You can change the app icon on iOS. However, it has to be shipped with the build before you upload it to the App Store. I mean, if you want to change the icon on some holidays, you need a strategy before that.

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/change-programmatically-your-app-icon-ios-swift-guide-3a8ee4f01649

Comment: Thank you @son is that possible for android too in any way?

Comment: I don't have experience with the Android platform, I'm sorry I can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

iOS doesn't natively support changing the app icon without submitting an update to the App Store. But you can include multiple app icons in the app bundle and then programmatically switch between them using the UIApplication class's setAlternateIconName method. This doesn't require an app update each time the icon changes but it does require the icons to be included in the original app bundle submitted to the store.

iOS Example:

```
if UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons {
    UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("appIconName") { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error changing app icon: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

You can check this article for more information on how to do it in iOS:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-change-your-app-icon-dynamically-with-setalternateiconname

Android allows more flexibility in dynamically changing app icons and other assets. You can use Android's manifest placeholders and resource directory qualifiers to change app icons based on certain conditions without an app update. Android apps can also download resources from a server and use them to update the app's appearance dynamically.

You can check this article for more information on how to do it in Android: https://medium.com/@agangurde333/change-android-app-launcher-icon-without-app-update-7f018375c49d